# I cannot delete a birthday event on my iPad 2

Tags: ios, calendar

I cannot delete a birthday event from my iPad 2 which I never put there. I attempt to delete the event and it comes right back.

Comment: Some more information may be nice. For example, if you have Facebook set up with Calendar Facebook birthday's will automatically get added to your calendar.

Comment: How did you try? Using which apps?

Answer (score 1):

You do not have to delete a contact's birthday to remove it from Calendar--unless it is the only birthday you want to remove. You can [subscribe/unsubscribe](https://support.apple.com/kb/ph2676?locale=en_US) to birthdays to allow them to show in Calendar.

> 1. In iCloud Calendar, click the Action pop-up menu  in the sidebar, then choose Preferences.
> 2. In the General pane, select “Show Birthdays calendar,” then click Save.
> 3. Show or hide the Birthdays calendar by turning it on or off in the Subscriptions section of the Calendars sidebar.

This will show all birthdays that have been added to your Contacts. If you want to show the other birthdays and important dates (as you can also add anniversaries and such) and exclude just one birthday, then you will have to remove that date from the contact's 'birthday' field.

> To modify a birth date, use iCloud Contacts; changes are reflected in iCloud Calendar within a day.

I have a few contacts where, instead of deleting their birthday altogether, I have moved their birthdays from the designated field and into the Notes field--no information lost and no reminders or Calendar events.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, what I ended up doing was changing the event type you click the event and click on calendar then change the calendar color (purple to yellow, etc). Then go into the calendars menu from the main calendar page and disable that color. Tedious but it worked for me.

Answer (score -2):

It may be due to a contact having a birthday, in which case the simplest thing to do would be to go to your contact on the phone and remove their birthday.

Answer (score -2):

I had the same problem. It's via birthdays free app and will it be removed after uninstallation.

Answer (score -2):

Something called 'Lone's birthday' suddenly appeared on my calendar and I couldn't delete it. When the birthday date finally arrived I went into birthday calendar edit and deleted it and all future notifications then. But I'd lived with it for six months!